# Expand backgorund image depending on the content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this background image which I'm using. There's this section known as the user profile area, where I'm using jQuery tabs. The content for some tab is less, and for some the content is pretty wide. But when the content is wide, the image doesn't display till the end.

Here's an example.

When the content is less (displays correctly).
[image]

Long content, displays incorrectly.
[image]

Here's my CSS code for body. What changes should I make here?

```
body{
    /*background:rgba(226, 235, 238, 1);*/

    color:#545454;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;    color:#7d7e80;
    font-size:14px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.gordonviaggi.it/files/wedding_packets/in_giro_per_san_francisco.jpeg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cant re-create it cause it seems to be working fine. Have you tried `height:100%;`

Comment: try setting a height of 100%? @JSG, just saw your post...oops :)

Answer (score 0):

try height:100%;
 if that does'nt fix you can create a new class for bgimg and mention 
position:absolute;
 width:100%, 
height:100%; 
top:0%;
left:0%;
that works for me everytime. :) all the best

Answer (score 0):

For your background-size, try this:

> background-size:100% 100%;

Additionally, background-size is supported in a large percentage of browsers, although not 100% of them.  Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) to see if you're browser is one of them.